# How to turn off Quick Info inVS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I need to turn Quick Info off in my VS10. The biggest problem is not the code obstruction but i have installed some extensions and this original Quick Info is overpainting the info shown by the extension.

Comment: which language are you using? i think it's only possible to turn it off in c sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C/C++, you'd set Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Auto Quick Info to False.

Comment: think you can only turn it off for these languages

Comment: I am using C#. I looked at it and it is as you said.